# How to add elements from one array to another?

Tags: android, class, arraylist

I have a class called people that has its own name, id etc...
I have a full list of people in an array list `public ArrayList<people> pList;`
When I click on some names I want to add the people in pList to `public ArrayList<people> followList;` Doing followList.add(pList.get(position)) doesn't work. What is the proper way to do this.

Also, on another click I would like to remove the particular object from the followList so I tried doing followList.remove(pList.get(position)) but obviously it doesn't work as well.

Im basically trying to have a list of people from the original list.

Comment: it sais im getting a null pointer exception

Comment: Have you initialized `followList` with something like `new ArrayList<people>()`?

Comment: good catch, make an answer and i will check it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `followList` seems to be not initialized. You should call initialize it with `new ArrayList<people>()` before adding to or removing from it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have instantiated the `ArrayList followList`, and that there is in fact a element at pList[position]?

Comment: If there was no element at the specified position then `IndexOutOfBoundsException` would be thrown.